# AWS DNS by default routing http after i have config https

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, https

I have deployed one application in tomcat on AWS ec2 and Linked with DNS through rout 53. created ALP load balancer and configured SSL. if we access with HTTS then Site is working. If i access [www.oursite.com](http://www.oursite.com) the by default it is taking http instead https.

Please help if any one phase same.

Answer (score 0):

Have you configure your ALB Listener correctly?
It should either

- Only have HTTPS
- Have both HTTPS and HTTP but with a redirection to HTTPS using custom Listener Rules.